# I'm looking to patent a new SaaS Education System. Processes and structure are very different from the traditional system

Tags: patentability, intellectual-property, system, business, education

I am aware that I cannot disclose key information about the system/business model but I would only need to know if there is record of previous education systems being patented. It isn't just a software but an entire educational process, explained in detail.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly many patents that cover educational systems. A few that came up in a quick search:

> Online educational system with multiple navigational modes
> [US8727781B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8727781)
>
> Vertically integrated mobile educational system [US9324240B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9324240B2/en?oq=US9324240B2)
>
> Real time learning and self improvement educational system and method
> [US8602793B1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8602793B1/en?oq=US8602793B1)
>
> On-line educational system having an electronic notebook feature
> [US6965752B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6965752B2/en?oq=US6965752B2)

You need to do a better search if you are interested in moving forward.

Comment: Added additional links.